# Error -1073741819 y segmentation fault al usar strlen en C

Tags: c

El problema surge cuando utilizo la función `Vigenere`, ya que dentro de la misma necesito hacer una evaluación de la longitud de `frase`, pero esto me genera dicho error. Lo extraño es que en otras funciones también utilicé la función `strlen` con frase y la misma no me generó errores. Probé utilizando el debugger y siguiendo el valor de `strlen(frase)` con watches, el valor es correcto hasta antes de ingresar a la función `GeneraVigenere`, al salir el programa automáticamente me da error (esto recién pasa en el for si no uso watches), supongo entonces que el error se genera allí, aunque no veo por qué.

El call stack:

```
#0 0x76d49cc0   strlen() (C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll:??)
#1 0x40189f Vigenere(frase=0x1b1a1918 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x1b1a1918>)
```

El código es el siguiente, no incluí aquellas funciones que no son relevantes al problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Cesar(char []);
void CesarModificado(char []);
void Vigenere(char []);
void GeneraVigenere(char [][94]);
void MostrarTabla(char [][94]);

int main()
{
    char frase[200];
    int met;
    printf("Ingrese la frase a encriptar\n");
    gets(frase);
    printf("0 para Cesar. 1 para Cesar modificado. 2 para Vigenere\n");
    scanf("%d", &met);
    switch (met){
        case (0): Cesar(frase);
        break;
        case (1): CesarModificado(frase);
        break;
        case (2): Vigenere(frase);
    }
    printf("Frase encriptada:\n");
    printf("%s", frase);
    return 0;
}

void Vigenere(char frase[]){
    char Tabla[94][94], clave[200];
    int i, j=0;
    GeneraVigenere(Tabla);
    printf("Introduzca la clave\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(clave);
    for (i=0; i<strlen(frase); i++) {
        if (j==strlen(clave))
            j=0;
        frase[i]= Tabla[(int)frase[i]-32][(int)clave[j]-32];
    }
    printf("Tabla:\n");
    MostrarTabla(Tabla);
}

void GeneraVigenere(char Tabla[][94]) {
    int i=0, j=0, salto=0;
    for (i=0; i<=94; i++)
        for (j=0; j<=94; j++) {
            Tabla[i][j]=(char) ((j+salto)%95);
        }
        salto++;
}
```

Si necesitan que añada algo más sólo díganme, gracias!

Comment: En la función Vigenere, llevo un rato dándole vueltas y me parece que no estás incrementando ni cambiando de valor nunca la j, siempre vale 0... Esa era tu intención o se trata de un error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for (i=0; i<=94; i++)
> ```

Las formaciones empiezan por cero. Así que los elementos van del `0` al `93`. Si accedes al 94ésimo elemento, estás accediendo fuera de la memoria asignada y generando una posible violación de segmento. Seguramente lo que querías hacer es esto:

```
void GeneraVigenere(char Tabla[][94]) {
    int i=0, j=0, salto=0;
    for (i=0; i < 94; i++)
//              ^ <-- Menor estricto
        for (j=0; j < 94; j++) {
//                  ^ <-- Menor estricto
            Tabla[i][j]=(char) ((j+salto)%95);
        }
        salto++;
}
```